# Update table from another table: Difference between using inner join and update multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to update table 1 column 'num' with the value in table2.

might be really basic.. but I could not find the difference between using
`inner join` and `update table x, y where xxxx` in this scenario.

let's say I have two tables:

```
table1 
name | num
name1  1
name2  2
name3  3

table2
name | num
name1  11
name2  22
name4  44
```

what I want is:

table1:

```
name | num
name1  11
name2  22
name3  3
```

I could achieve this by running

Method1:

```
UPDATE table1, table2
SET table1.num = table2.num
where table1.name = table2.name
```

and

Method2:

```
UPDATE table1
inner join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
SET table1.num = table2.num
```

I get the same result and I was wondering if I can use either one.. or is there any difference between these two queries??
I think I need use method1 to update both table..
but if I want to update only 1 table like in this scenario, does it matter which query I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two are functionally equivalent -- and both are non-standard SQL syntax (i.e. MySQL extensions).  They should produce the same execution plan as well.

That said, I recommend the version with the `JOIN`.  In my opinion, `JOIN` is *always* preferable over commas.